# Deny access to AWS S3 files for everyone but the application user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am creating a web application where users sign in via Amazon Cognito. Once a user is logged in he can start uploading and downloading files from AWS S3 using a pre-signed url. The files are supposed to be secret and only the user who uploaded them should be able to read them. Is it possible to achieve this so that even the AWS account's root user cannot read the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html), there is an option to use client-side encryption out of box.

```
 EncryptionMaterials encryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(symKey);

 AmazonS3 s3EncryptionClient = AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder.standard()
       .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
       .withEncryptionMaterials(new StaticEncryptionMaterialsProvider(encryptionMaterials))
        .withRegion(clientRegion)
        .build();
```

Please note:

- if the client will need to provide an extra key to encrypt the content. The question is how / where will the client manage the content key. (PBKDF? KMS from different account?)
- if the encryption key is lost, the content is unrecoverable

> I mean if the encryption key is saved on the user's end and he deletes the application and all of it's data, how is he able to decrypt the data after installing the application again?

I suggest you to create a [password-based encryption key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), where the user could provide an encryption password (different from user's authentication password which may change).

> Maybe I can use Cognito password for this, but what if the user wants to change the password

You (should) have no access to user's password.

Answer (score 1):

Only way to get this method to work is that the user will have to encrypt the file on their side, and then upload encrypted file, when they download the file later, it is decrypted so they can read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any suggestions how to manage client side encryption. Or more specifically what to encrypt it whit? I mean if the encryption key is saved on the user's end and he deletes the application and all of it's data, how is he able to decrypt the data after installing the application again? Maybe I can use Cognito password for this, but what if the user wants to change the password?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html